# ВОЗМОЖНА ли такая пунктуация?

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение, вводное-слово

***Я начал развивать свой канал, возможно кому-то понравится***;

***Кто знает, может (это) и получится***;

***Не знаю, наверное это и будет***.

Обратите внимание на выделенное слово в вопросе. То есть мне не важно, рекомендуется или нет, — мне важно, можно ли так ставить по правилам вводного слова между частей СП.

Если нельзя, то подскажите, как можно. Другие варианты предлагайте, **если нельзя так, как я сказал**, просто так это делать необязательно.

Answer (score 3):

Ни за что. Вводное должно быть обособлено.

Желательна такая постановка знаков:

*Я начал развивать свой канал - возможно, кому-то понравится;*

*Кто знает - может, и получится;*

*Не знаю - наверное, это и будет.*

Альтернативой тире может быть только двоеточие.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148745/discussion-on-answer-by-galina-avanesova----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: У Розенталя правило есть (естественно, в параграфе о вводных словах), только вот Лопатин ввёл реформу и расширил область действия правила об обособленных оборотах до сложных предложений.

Comment: А почему в Ваших примерах вместо тире стоит дефис? Надо именно тире ставить, дефис — орфографический знак.